# How to create a composite React.js component from components in multiple jsx files

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning how to program with React.js and do not understand how to create a composite React.js component from components in multiple jsx files.  I am able to make composite components from individual components inside a single jsx file, but when I try to use a component from one jsx file in the other jsx file, the component is not recognized (out of scope).  I'm not sure if it matters, but I am using Visual Studio 2015 for my IDE and the two jsx files are part of the Visual Studio project.

Comment: Could you show us your attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import them like this.

```js
import React from 'react';

import DropDownMenu from './dropdown.menu';
import DropDownSelect from './dropdown.select';

let AppCtrlSty = {
  height: '100%',
  padding: '0 10px 0 0'
}

let DropDownSty = {
  border: 'solid 1px darkslategrey',
  height: 'calc(100% - 10px)',
  overflow: 'auto',
  paddingLeft: '0',
  width: '33%'
}

export default class AppCtrl extends React.Component {
   render() {
    return (
      <div id='AppCtrlSty' style={AppCtrlSty}>
        React 1.4 DropDown<br/><br/>
        <div id='menuColumns' className='FlexBox' style={{height: '100%'}}>
          <div id='DropDownMenu' style={DropDownSty}>
            <DropDownMenu />
          </div>
          <div id='DropDownSelect' style={DropDownSty}>
            <DropDownSelect />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```